# Peek and Pop not an option

Tags: ios, swift, segue, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to implement Peek and Pop into an app. There's only one issue- I don't have the option with my current segue setup:

[image: Segue Setup]

What am I doing wrong, and why do I not have this option?

Comment: From [the Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/Add3DSegue.html): "Note: Peek and pop segues added through the storyboard require a target of iOS 9.1 or later." Is your target set appropriately high?

Comment: Yep, that is set to 9.1

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post some more information? Additional pictures, classes of the VC, etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How are you establishing your segue? This is poorly documented, but setting up 3D Touch segues from a Storyboard appears to be unavailable if you're using a *Manual Segue* (controller to controller) versus an *Action Segue* (object to controller).

To illustrate, here's a *Manual Segue* with 3D Touch segues absent:

[image]

Here's an *Action Segue* with 3D Touch segues present:

[image]